# Typeahead Bootstrap Working on Local But Not on Production Server

Tags: php, json, bootstrap-typeahead

i have some problem i couldn't figure. I have written the function to get autocomplete searching system using Type-ahead.

This function works perfectly in localhost machine, but when it uploaded to server, the function is broken.

Here's my type-ahead syntax:

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#q').typeahead({
                 source: function(query, process){
                     $.ajax({
                         url:'autosearch.php',
                         type:'POST',
                         data:'query=' + query,
                         dataType: 'JSON',
                         async: true,
                         success:function(data){
                             process(data);
                         }
                     });
                 }
             })
         });   
        </script>
```

It get value from text input (html below)

```
<form method="GET" action="search.php" class="form-inline pull-right">
                        <input name="q" id="q" class="span5" type="text"  placeholder="search" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="icon-search icon-white"></i></button>
                    </form>
```

what's wrong with this function?

thanks

**UPDATE**

After getting result from firebug, it shows that error occured on php file

Notice:  Undefined index: q in **C:\xampp\htdocs\kbase\panel\autosearch.php** on line 5

the php code is like this:

```
<?php 
require_once "configuration.php";
$q = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_GET['q']));

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT title as title FROM ** WHERE title LIKE '%" . $q ."%'";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
$cname = array();

while ($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsd)) 
{
    $cname[] = $rs['title'];
}
 echo json_encode($cname);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autosearch.php` is sent a `POST` request and not a `GET` one. It's also sending the variable name as `query` and not `q`.

As a head's up, you can simplify the ajax query:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#q').typeahead({
        source: function(query, process) {
            $.ajax({
                url:'autosearch.php',
                type:'POST', // <- defaults to GET (desired by your PHP)
                data:'query=' + query, // <- change to {'q': query} for your PHP
                dataType: 'JSON', // <- 'json' LOWERCASE
                async: true, // <- defaults to true anyway
                success: process // <- same function signature
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: yes, thanks pickypg, i have rename the jquery query to q only. i just add some isset from GET, try to change it to POST method

Comment: If you want it to be a `POST` request, then change the `$_GET` to `$_POST` and leave the `type` set to `POST` in the Ajax call.